# Pegar valores separados por vírgula do banco de dados e organizá-los em <li>

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho no meu banco de dados, dentro da minha tabela "db_home_content" a coluna "a2_content_x_imploders" ("x" seria o respectivo número do content, como representado na imagem) que contém alguns dados separados por vírgula. Exemplo: `Site em HTML5, Alta velocidade, Responsivo`.

Preciso pegar esses dados e organizá-los, de acordo com a quantidade, em `<li>`'s assim como apresentado na imagem.
[image: imagem demonstrativa]
Existe alguma função em PHP ou MySQL que faça o contrário do implode? Se sim, como ela funciona para o meu caso?

Comment: Reverti a edição, pois foge do problema original e já respondido. Se tem alguma dúvida complementar, pergunte pros colegas abaixo nos comentários, ou abra uma nova pergunta só sobre a parte diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim!
Função `explode()`.

Exemplo:

```
$lista = "item1,item2,item3";
$lista = explode(",", $lista);
// Aqui lista passou a ser um array("item1", "item2", "item3");
```

Para escrever os LIs, basta usar o foreach().

Exemplo:

```
$htmlLista = "ul";
foreach ($lista as $item) {
   $htmlLista .= "li".$item."li";
}
$htmlLista .= "ul";
echo $htmlLista;
// Lembre-se de adicionar < e > nas tags, não consigo adicionar na resposta pois estes caracteres são removidos.
```

Comment: Funcionou como queria! Existe possibilidade de passar cada valor separado para um input, num painel administrativo? Levando em consideração que o máximo de inputs será 8

Comment: Você pode criar os inputs da mesma maneira que os LIs foram criados, usando o foreach().

Comment: Já resolvi o problema. Achei melhor colocar eles "implodidos" no painel, com o plugin tags input. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Com Javascript, é possível separar o texto por vírgular, e adicionar os `li`:

```js
var texto = 'Site em HTML5, Alta velocidade, Responsivo'.split(',');
texto.forEach(function(item) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = item;
  document.getElementById("siteFit").appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Site Fit</h3>
<ul id="siteFit"></ul>
```

Comment: Funcionaria bem, mas no caso, precisarei, posteriormente passar cada resultado como value de um input diferente.

Comment: @DanielBonifácio Você nem menciona input na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conteudo = 'Site em HTML5, Alta velocidade, Responsivo';

$conteudoArray = explode(',', $conteudo);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($conteudoArray as $conteudo) {
    echo'<li>' . $conteudo . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```